Display record based on record type and and industry and show a green button icon if account is active using lwc how to implement
Write a LWC component to display Account records in lightning-datatable and show checkbox
field (IsActive) as an image (true: green check, false: red cross). Please don’t use @wire
adapters.
Please add a filter with 3 dropdowns on top of lightning-datatable to handle the rows filtering.
● The first dropdown contains the names of available Record Types on Account.
● The second dropdown contains the names of available fields of type Picklist on Account.
● Third dropdown’s values are based on selection of Record Type dropdown & Picklist
dropdown. It should show the available values of selected picklist for selected record
type in the dropdownenter image description here
I asked to implement this using lwc and i implemented till filtering the data in data table but how to show green and red icon based on account status is a challenge for me ,can someone please guide me

I have worked on this and found the below solutions, I am posting it here along with all the code and it's explanation.

Approach Which I follow:

a) First I created an apex class which was having a method to fetch account records on the basis of recordtype, field and it’s respective value. All three values were passing through parameter from LWC javascript while calling the class.
b) Created two more methods to get recordTypes and Picklist fields and their respective values from salesforce using Schema.describe methods and then used them on LWC.
c) LWC JS file was importing all 3 methods from apexclass and later the same created adaptors were being used as per requirements.
d) Since wire was not supposed to be used, and hence used imperative apex calling here, which was made through the connected callback.
e) HTML was displaying the lightning card having 3 dropdowns for Record Type, Fields and Value selection, their downtown options was being controlled over JS of same component and the display panel for records was using lightning data table.
f) I used Cellattributes and dynamicicons in order to work with active and inactive accounts icon display, and in data panel it was being controlled for both types of accounts.
g) LWC configuration was exposed and set all 3 types of app builder supported pages as target.
h) Lastly created an apex test class for the used controller which is having 72% of code coverage as of now.

Code snippets for Apex class, Test Class and LWC Component:

a) Apex Class:
public with sharing class AccountController {
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Account> getAccounts(String recordTypeId, String picklistField, String picklistValue) {
       String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, IsActive__c FROM Account';
      
       if (recordTypeId != null && picklistField != null && picklistValue != null) {
           query += ' WHERE RecordTypeId = :recordTypeId AND ' + picklistField + ' = :picklistValue';
       }
      
       return Database.query(query + ' LIMIT 100');
   }


   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<RecordType> getAccountRecordTypes() {
       return [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' with SECURITY_ENFORCED];
   }


   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Map<String, String>> getPicklistValues(String picklistField) {
       List<Map<String, String>> picklistOptions = new List<Map<String, String>>();
      
       // Get the field describe result for the picklist field
       Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(picklistField).getDescribe();
       List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
      
       // Convert PicklistEntry objects to a list of Maps (serializable)
       for (Schema.PicklistEntry entry : picklistEntries) {
           if (entry.isActive()) {
               Map<String, String> picklistOption = new Map<String, String>();
               picklistOption.put('label', entry.getLabel());
               picklistOption.put('value', entry.getValue());
               picklistOptions.add(picklistOption);
           }
       }
      
       return picklistOptions;
   }


}

b) Test Class
@isTest
public class AccountControllerTest {
  
   @isTest
   static void testGetAccountsWithFilter() {
       // Create test data
       RecordType customerRT = [select Id,Name from RecordType where sObjectType='Account' and Name='Customer' with SECURITY_ENFORCED limit 1];
       Schema.SObjectField picklistField = Account.IsActive__c;
      
       Account acc = new Account();
           acc.Name = 'Test Account';
           acc.RecordTypeId = customerRT.Id;
           acc.Type = 'Prospect';
           acc.Industry = 'Education';
       insert acc;


       // Test the getAccounts method with filters
       Test.startTest();
       List<Account> accounts = AccountController.getAccounts(customerRT.Id, 'Type', 'Prospect');
       Test.stopTest();


       // Verify the results
       System.assertNotEquals(null, accounts, 'Accounts should not be null');
       System.assertEquals(1, accounts.size(), 'There should be one account returned');
       System.assertEquals(acc.Id, accounts[0].Id, 'The account Id should match');
   }
  
   @isTest
   static void testGetAccountsWithoutFilter() {
       // Create test data
       Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type = 'Prospect', Industry = 'Education');
       insert acc;


       // Test the getAccounts method without filters
       Test.startTest();
       List<Account> accounts = AccountController.getAccounts(null, null, null);
       Test.stopTest();


       // Verify the results
       System.assertNotEquals(null, accounts, 'Accounts should not be null');
       System.assertEquals(accounts.size() > 0,true);
   }


   @isTest
   static void testGetAccountRecordTypes() {
       // Create test data
       RecordType vendorRT = [select Id,Name from RecordType where sObjectType='Account' and Name='Vendor' with SECURITY_ENFORCED limit 1];


       // Test the getAccountRecordTypes method
       Test.startTest();
       List<RecordType> recordTypes = AccountController.getAccountRecordTypes();
       Test.stopTest();


       // Verify the results
       System.assertNotEquals(null, recordTypes, 'Record types should not be null');
       System.assertEquals(recordTypes.size() > 0, true);
   }
  
   @isTest
   static void testGetPicklistValues() {
       // Create a custom picklist field
       Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('IsActive__c').getDescribe();
       List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
      
       // Test the getPicklistValues method
       Test.startTest();
       List<Map<String, String>> picklistOptions = AccountController.getPicklistValues('IsActive__c');
       Test.stopTest();


       // Verify the results
       System.assertNotEquals(null, picklistOptions, 'Picklist options should not be null');
       System.assertEquals(picklistOptions.size() > 0, false);
      
       // Validate that picklist values are present and match the picklist entries
       for (Map<String, String> option : picklistOptions) {
           System.assertNotEquals(null, option.get('label'), 'Label should not be null');
           System.assertNotEquals(null, option.get('value'), 'Value should not be null');
       }
   }
}

c) Lightning web Component name: accountDataTable:
I) accountDataTable.js File
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
import getAccountRecordTypes from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountRecordTypes';
import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getPicklistValues';


export default class AccountDataTable extends LightningElement {
   @track data = [];
   @track columns = [
       { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
       {
           label: 'Active',
           fieldName: 'IsActive__c',
           cellAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName: 'dynamicIcon' } }
       }
   ];
   @track recordTypes = [];
   @track picklistFields = [];
   @track picklistValues = [];
   @track selectedRecordType = '';
   @track selectedPicklistField = '';
   @track selectedPicklistValue = '';


   connectedCallback() {
       this.fetchRecordTypes();
       this.fetchAccounts();
   }


   fetchRecordTypes() {
       getAccountRecordTypes()
           .then((result) => {
               this.recordTypes = result.map(rt => ({ label: rt.Name, value: rt.Id }));
           })
           .catch((error) => {
               console.error('Error fetching record types: ', error);
           });
   }


   handleRecordTypeChange(event) {
       this.selectedRecordType = event.detail.value;
       this.selectedPicklistField = '';
       this.selectedPicklistValue = '';
       this.picklistValues = [];
       this.fetchPicklistFields();
   }


   fetchPicklistFields() {
       // Replace with your logic to fetch picklist fields (hardcoded or dynamic)
       this.picklistFields = [
           { label: 'Industry', value: 'Industry' },
           { label: 'Type', value: 'Type' },
           // Add other picklist fields here
       ];
   }


   handlePicklistFieldChange(event) {
       this.selectedPicklistField = event.detail.value;
       this.selectedPicklistValue = '';
       this.fetchPicklistValues();
   }


   fetchPicklistValues() {
       getPicklistValues({ recordTypeId: this.selectedRecordType, picklistField: this.selectedPicklistField })
           .then((result) => {
               this.picklistValues = result.map(pv => ({ label: pv.label, value: pv.value }));
           })
           .catch((error) => {
               console.error('Error fetching picklist values: ', error);
           });
   }


   handlePicklistValueChange(event) {
       this.selectedPicklistValue = event.detail.value;
       this.fetchAccounts();
   }


   fetchAccounts() {
       getAccounts({
           recordTypeId: this.selectedRecordType,
           picklistField: this.selectedPicklistField,
           picklistValue: this.selectedPicklistValue
       })
       .then((result) => {
           this.data = result.map(account => {
               return {
                   ...account,
                   IsActive: account.IsActive__c,
                   dynamicIcon : account.IsActive__c ? 'action:approval' : 'action:close',
               };
           });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.error('Error fetching accounts: ', error);
       });
   }
}

II) accountDataTable.html
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<!-- accountDataTable.html -->
<template>
   <lightning-card title="Account Data">
       <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
           <lightning-combobox
               name="recordType"
               label="Select Record Type"
               value={selectedRecordType}
               placeholder="Select Record Type"
               options={recordTypes}
               onchange={handleRecordTypeChange}>
           </lightning-combobox>
           <lightning-combobox
               name="picklistField"
               label="Select Picklist Field"
               value={selectedPicklistField}
               placeholder="Select Picklist Field"
               options={picklistFields}
               onchange={handlePicklistFieldChange}>
           </lightning-combobox>
           <lightning-combobox
               name="picklistValue"
               label="Select Picklist Value"
               value={selectedPicklistValue}
               placeholder="Select Picklist Value"
               options={picklistValues}
               onchange={handlePicklistValueChange}>
           </lightning-combobox>
       </div>
       <lightning-datatable
           key-field="Id"
           data={data}
           columns={columns}
           hide-checkbox-column="true"
           draft-values={draftValues}>
       </lightning-datatable>
   </lightning-card>
</template>

III) accountDataTable.js-metaxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
       <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
       <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
   </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

IV) accountDataTable.css
/* accountDataTable.css */
:host {
   display: block;
   margin: 20px;
}


.lightning-datatable {
   margin-top: 10px;
}`enter code here`

Hope this helps. All the best!!
